# UOM and UOM ratio incorrect on Pick Ticket

Tags: acumatica

We use UOM conversions at this client. We stock in Eaches and sell in Cases. The problem we are having with the Pick ticket is that both the quantity to be picked and the UOM being picked are the stocking unit and not the selling unit. 
e.g. The customer orders 73 cases (12 ea per case). The pick ticket prints 876 each. This requires the warehouse person to look up each item determine if there is a Selling UOM and ratio and to then manually convert 876 eaches to 73 cases.

Obviously, the pick ticket should print 73 cases. But I cannot find a way to do this. The items are lotted and an order of 73 case might have 50 cases of Lot A and 23 cases of Lot B. This is represented in the SOShipLineSplit table. The quantities and UOM in this table are based on Stocking units.

Ideally, I could join the INUnits table to both the SOSHipLine and SOShipLineSPlit table. See Below.

```
Select  case when isnull(U.UnitRate,0) = 0 then S.Qty else S.Qty/U.Unitrate end as ShipQty
,case when isnull(U.UnitRate,0) = 0 then s.uom else U.FromUnit end as UOM
from SOShipLineSplit S 
inner join SOShipLine SL
ON S.CompanyID = SL.CompanyID and s.ShipmentNbr = SL.ShipmentNbr and  S.LineNbr = SL.LineNbr and S.InventoryID = SL.InventoryID
Left Outer Join INUnit U
On S.CompanyID = U.CompanyID and S.InventoryID = U.InventoryID and s.UOm = U.ToUnit and SL.UOM = U.FromUnit
where S.ShipmentNbr = '000161' and S.CompanyId = 4
```

The problem is the Acumatica Report writer does not support a join with multiple tables.

```
Left Outer Join INUnit U
On S.CompanyID = U.CompanyID and S.InventoryID = U.InventoryID and s.UOm = U.ToUnit and SL.UOM = U.FromUnit
```

I believe I must be missing something. This cannot be the only client using Acumatica who utilizes Selling Units of Measure. Is there another table I could use that would contain the quantities and UOM already converted for this order to Selling Units?

Or another solution?

Thanks in advance.
pat

Comment: I would think join with multiple tables is supported. If you mean joining the same table multiple times, there should be a way to achieve it with Alias field in report schema builder or with DAC inheritance.

Comment: Hugues, I haven't be able to add Mulitple tables to the same Report Schema builder. Look closely at the multiple tables in my example. Particulary at the left hand side. The left hand side contains TWO tables. That is the issue. I cannot find a way to use two different tables in the left hand side. I do not know how to change DAC inheritance. However, What do you think of the idea of creating a TSQL VIEW, "AcumaticaDB.dbo.SOShipLineSplitUOM". Could that view be added to the report schema? If so, could you show me how? What are the downsides of doing this?

Comment: I just looked. There are multiple Schemas. To which Schema should my view be added?

Comment: SQL views are strongly discouraged. I see you have 2 joins, there's nothing unusual with that. Standard reports contain dozens of tables. I think you should brush up on documentation and learn how to add tables in join. Check Loading Database Schema and Building Database Request from following link: https://help-2018r1.acumatica.com/Wiki/ShowWiki.aspx?pageid=aca7408e-4d55-42de-b257-f150c06d23a6

Comment: There must be a single schema in a report, you're probably just confused here.

Comment: Hugues, First thank you for your patience and staying with me on this thread. I am only here because Support told me they could not assist me and that I should try here. I agree that multiple table joins are not uncommon. I do not know the individual names for the different parts of the query so I think I have not communicated my problem effectively. Look at the second join. See next comment

Comment: Left Outer Join INUnit U
On SOShipLineSplit.CompanyID = INUnit.CompanyID <==No Problem
and SOShipLineSplit.InventoryID = INUnit.InventoryID   <==NoProblem
and SOShipLineSplit.UOm = INUnit.ToUnit <== No Problem
and SOShipLine.UOM = INUnit.FromUnit  <== Problem: SOShipLine is the second table to appear on the Left Hand side in this join.  It is the last AND in the ON part of this second table join. All the other ANDs use SOSipLineSplit. This AND uses a different table SOShipLine. I am trying to use the reportwriter to add SOShipLine without success.

Comment: With SQL when you need to join the same table multiple time you need to give it an alias. Same thing goes in report designer, in the top grid set Parent Alias/Child Alias to bring in the same table in multiple joins.

Comment: > I am only here because Support told me they could not assist me and that I should try here.
- It's likely they expect you to have gone through training material for free support which is limited to 30 min (not long enough to teach you the basics).

Comment: Besides that I still have a lot of difficulty to understand your issue here. It is not clear what the problem is exactly. "I am trying to use the reportwriter to add SOShipLine without success." is not enough detail to understand where you're failing

Comment: Maybe you mean that you can't reference multiple tables in the join condition? If that's the case, look more carefully in the available values from the combo box because it is supported.

Comment: By clicking the Parent Formula button on the Relationships tab of Schema Builder you can describe the second table, SOShipLine, such as =[SOShipLine.UOM] for the left-hand side of that active relation. Is that helpful for this issue?

Answer (score 0):

**EDIT:**

If the goal is to display accurate quantities before/after conversion then INUnit DAC can't be used. It doesn't store historical data, you can change INUnit values after an order has been finalized so re-using it to compute quantities will not yield accurate results.

For that scenario you would need to use the historical data fields with `Base` prefixes like ShippedQuantity/BaseShippedQuantity. If you require to store more historical data you need to add a custom field to hold these values and update them when shipment is created/modified.

---

The main issue appears to be a logical error in the requirement:

> The problem is that the INUnit table has to be joined to BOTH the
>   SOShipLine and the SOShipLineSplit tables.

INUnit DAC has a single parent, not 2 so you need to change your requirement to reflect that constraint.

If SOShipLine and SOShipLineSplit values differ then you'll never get any record.

If they are identical then there's no need to join on both since they have the same value.

---

I suggest to add 2 joins, one for SOShipLine and another for SOShipLineSplit. In the report you can choose which one to display (1st, 2nd or both). 
You can also add visibility conditions or IIF formula condition in the report if you want to handle null values error check for display purpose.

Use the Child Alias property in schema builder to join the same table 2 times without name conflicts. In the report formulas (to display field or in formula conditions) use the Child Alias table name too.

Example:
[image]

Comment: Notice that a similar pattern is used to get the shipment note (ShipNote alias) and the sales order note (SOLineNote alias). Since Note has a single parent you can't join on both sales order and shipment table so you need two joins with alias to fetch both notes separately.